# Insert and display records in same view in Asp.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in mvc3. I learned how we can insert ,display and update records in separate views.
But how can i do all these operations in single view? That is user will be able to insert records from the top of the page(view) and  also can see the listing of all the records at the bottom of page and also will be able to update from the same page(view).
Thanks

Comment: why not..just change your code for a single view.

Comment: can u please provide me a piece of code for the view.as right now for displaying records i am using "foreach" which works with "IEnumerable"  before model name .But for submitting form i use @Html.Labelfor(m=>m.name) which does not work with "IEnumerable".So how can i collaborate both the things.

Answer (score 0):

Add a contoller and a single view...below is a rough example.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //code to display
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  //code to delete 
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, string name)
{
  //code to update
}
```

Comment: I got it.But can you provide me rough code of View which will be able to display records(in a grid table) and insert record?

Comment: no ways. since u r learning mvc take it as an homework. read more about mvc and ull discover the idea urself. Happy Coding :) ALL THE BEST